# c++ access_once

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the Linux macro `ACCESS_ONCE` in c++11.
`ACCESS_ONCE(x)` takes the address of x, casts to a pointer to a volatile of the same type as x, then dereferences it. This forces the compiler to not optimize out accesses to x through this macro (and make the access occur only once here).

My attempt to do it in c++11 involves `decltype`:

```
#define ACCESS_ONCE(x) (*static_cast<decltype(x) volatile *>(&(x)))
```

This works for most cases but I use it once like so:

```
void foo(void **bar) {
  while (ACCESS_ONCE(*bar) != NULL)
    ;
}
```

This fails with an error:

```
'volatile' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'void*&'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The correct cast here is `const_cast`, which, despite its name, can add and remove `volatile` qualifiers as well as `const` qualifiers.

Comment: @PeteBecker I disagree. `static_cast` is the correct choice here. `const_cast` is more powerful than necessary. `static_cast` is allowed to add cv-qualifiers because this conversion is always safe. `const_cast` should be reserved for cases that actually need an unsafe cast that *removes* a cv-qualifier.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - `static_cast` is more powerful than necessary because it's allowed to change types.

Comment: @PeteBecker with the exception of upcasting, `static_cast` only performs safe conversions. The primary use of `const_cast` is unsafe, since removing cv-qualifiers can easily result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - sigh. The cast is being used here to **add** volatile, not remove it. Unlike `static_cast`, `const_cast` here describes what it's being used for.

Comment: @PeteBecker using `const_cast` gives the incorrect impression that it's being used for an unsafe conversion.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - that's a circular argument: you insist it should only be used for "unsafe" conversions, so its use gives **you** that impression. It tells me that cv-qualifiers are being modified. Whether the changes are "safe" is secondary to whether they're **correct**, and if I want to review correctness, I'd much rather have a hint that only the cv-qualifiers are being changed.

Comment: @PeteBecker the vast majority of uses of const_cast are to remove cv-qualifiers because in most cases they are added implicitly.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - so, your point is that you will **assume** that it's being used to remove cv-qualifiers, because that's how it's mostly used? That's not sound engineering.

Comment: @PeteBecker my point is that since most uses of const_cast are unsafe, using const_cast draws attention that isn't deserved when doing something safe like adding cv-qualifiers.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple - and my point is that, since most uses of `static_cast` are to change the **type** of an object and not its cv-qualifiers, using `static_cast` draws attention that isn't deserved when doing something safe like adding cv-qualifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the macro to this:

```
#define ACCESS_ONCE(x) (*static_cast<std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type volatile *>(&(x)))
```

Dereferencing a pointer results in a reference. The macro is trying to cast it to a `void *& volatile` instead of a `void * volatile` like you want. You can't apply the volatile qualifier to a reference type so you have to use std::remove_reference to change it to the normal non-reference type.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the problem and taught me some c++11 tricks.

Comment: avoid macros -- they are for C hackers

Answer (score 7):

```
template<typename T>
inline T volatile &access_once(T &t) {
    return static_cast<T volatile &>(t);
}
```

This avoids macros, is simpler because the type deduction and reference removal is implicit in the template signature and it avoids the redundant address-of and deference operators (static casting between reference types is defined to do the same things as taking the address, casting and then dereferencing). It's just as performant and I don't think it depends on anything in C++11.

Comment: Would it work on already volatile objects (how volatile do you want it to be)? I suggest using remove_volatile on T in return statement and return type.

Comment: It actually does work on volatile objects. The redundant volatile is legal and doesn't cause any problems.